# Proving a limit via substitution and L'Hospital

Tags: calculus, limits

**Problem:** Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}2n\ell\tan(\pi/n)=2\pi\ell$.

**Attempt:** Let $t=\frac{\pi}{n}$. Then we have the following:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}2n\ell\tan(\pi/n)
&= \lim_{t\to0}\frac{2\pi\ell\tan(t)}{t} \tag{by substitution}\\[1em]
&= \lim_{t\to0}\frac{2\pi\ell\sec^2(t)}{1} \tag{by L'Hospital}\\[1em]
&= 2\pi\ell.
\end{align*}

Does this justification look right? (Been a while since using L'Hospital.)

Comment: You should say $\lim_{t\to 0^+}$, and its perfectly fine btw.

Comment: Yes that's right!

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}2nl\tan{\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)}$$
$$=2l\pi\lim_{\frac{\pi}{n}\to0}\frac{\tan{\frac{\pi}{n}}}{\frac{\pi}{n}}$$
$$=2l\pi\left(1\right)=2\pi l$$